# Is it Haram to read LGBT+fanfiction?

Tags: halal-haram

There is a fictional character that I really like and read fanfiction about and in a lot of fanfictions he's in a relationship with another male character I don't read anything that involves sex or anything explicit the only reason I read it because I want to see more exploration of his character and I know that I will not be affected by this and I won't get a  girlfriend nor a boyfriend because I am not interested in relationships (I don't even plan on getting married) is it Haram?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is haram. Such relationships are prohibited in Islam, as far as is known. This also applies to reading fictional stories.